# Error with connecting ftp through php 

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to connect to my server using php script to upload some files...

But it doesn't connect...

I dont know what is the error...

I'm sure that ftp is enable, i checked it through php_info()

What may be the error...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
$ftp_server = "server.com";  //address of ftp server (leave out ftp://)
$ftp_user_name = "Username"; // Username
$ftp_user_pass = "Password";   // Password

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);        // set up basic connection

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass);

if ($login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass)) {
    echo "Connected as ,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass \n";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect \n";
}
.....
.....
....
....
ftp_close($conn_id); // close the FTP stream
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you have to turn on the passive mode by doing:

```
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

directly after your `ftp_login`

**PS:** why do you do a double login? write

```
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass);

if ($login_result) {
```

instead of

```
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass);

if ($login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass)) {
```

Comment: I tried it and still the error as  "Couldn't connect " is displayed..

i removed the extra connect stmt

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong to me:

```
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass);

if ($login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass)) {
```

You should just need:

```
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass);

if ($login_result) {
```

Otherwise it will attempt to log in twice, this could be the issue.

Also try adding `or die` to the `ftp_conect` to see if it can even connect to server.

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the server you're trying to connect actually accepts connections from wherever this script is running from by using a regular FTP client. Your code may be correct but the FTP server isn't accepting connections from your server, or there's a firewall blocking things.
2. Most PHP functions will log error information internally that you can retrieve with [`error_get_last()`](http://php.net/error_get_last) and/or $php_errormsg. Some diagnostic information as to why the login call is failing may be stored in there.